# Recoding multiple columns at once

Tags: r, time-series, recode

I wonder how to recode an array of columns in R - none of the answers in Stackoverflow have worked for me so far.

I have education level (`ed_level_yy`) from 2005-2015, however, as the data frame is structured at the moment the columns are not exactly next to each other, but 'broken up' by education field columns (`ed_fi_yy`).

At the moment the columns consist of 'education codes', i.e. "100" will be recoded to "10 Hgh School" in ed_level. The `ed_level_yy` is a `character` variable.

I have tried making a vector:

```
ed_level <- c("ed_level_05", "ed_level_06", "ed_level07", "ed_level08", ...)
```

and then using it like this:

```
library(car)
df[ed_level] <- lapply(df[ed_level], 
function(x) recode (x, recodes = "'100'='10 High School'; '250' = '10 High School'; '120' = '30 Masters'"))`
```

It does not show an error, but it just doesn't change the variables. I have also tried this solution:

```
df[,ed_level] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,ed_level],
function(x) ifelse (x == '100', '10 High School', 
ifelse(x == '250', '10 High School', 
ifelse(x == '120', '30 Masters',x)))))`
```

However, this does not work either. I should say, that I have around 200 different 'codes', so anything that could  'bundle' them would also be appreciated - i.e. `if '100' or '150' = '10 High School'.

Comment: IMO, this would be easier if you convert your data to a long, tidy format.  Then if you have a lookup table (e.g. two columns of all Codes and relevant Recodes), you can just perform an inner join with your long table.

Comment: how is the link between new codes and old codes stored ?

Comment: What is the `cars` package? I'm not sure where you're getting `df`. Could you provide us with your data frame, a minimal example of it?

Comment: you might just need a join

Comment: @rica Its worth adding a small reproducible example for this question.